# Help us save a dying language with only 1 speaker left!

Tags: historical-linguistics, language-acquisition, comparative-linguistics, sociolinguistics, language-revival

It's difficult to do this single-handedly, so I could use some professional help. :) I'm a professor of Ancient Egyptian (and cosmology as well, which means I'm a perfect target for conspiracy theorists regarding aliens and pyramids, so bring it on!) from the University of Zagreb (yeah, that's somewhere in the Balkans), and I deal with comparative linguistics, so I like dead languages. However, I also want that alive ones stay like that.

Yaghan language is a language isolate from Tierra del Fuego. That means that my historical linguistics and comparative linguistics knowledge isn't much of use, and the whole process of learning this language is quite difficult. However, it's more difficult for Cristina Calderon, the last native speaker of this language. Imagine havine no one to talk to in your mother tongue. That could be a dream sometimes, but it's usually a nightmare.

So, join us at [facebook.com/SaveYaghan](http://facebook.com/SaveYaghan). My plan is to publish bits of grammar and interesting words I find from time to time, in order to experiment with social media, to start the revitalization of this language. Unfortunately, Beyonce didn't retweet me, so I've lost kids as possible new speakers, but all is not lost! :D We're also on twitter: @SaveYaghan. Warning: I spam a lot, in order to get some attention. You can help by retweeting.

This is the most famous part of Yaghan:

[image: Mamihlapinatapai]

However, there's even more fascinating stuff that we can discover. Help me put the Internet to a good cause. I promise each one of you an exoplanet of your choice after I conquer the Laniakea supercluster.  Darmok & Jalad at Tanagra!

Comment: Kristina, welcome to Linguistics SE. Sorry, but this is a Q&A site (not a forum), so we don't allow "non-question" posts, and while I am sympathetic to your cause (truly am), I need to enforce the site model by closing your post. Wish you good luck in your mission and hope you stick around for more questions and answers!